# SQL Server 2012 on windows 8

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to install SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on Windows 8. After installing, I am unable to connect to local server and when I check SQL Configuration Manager, I found out that no sql services is running. I re-installed it many times but still no luck. Why sql services is not running ?

Comment: If you just installed management studio, that's not going to include the database engine.

Comment: So you're installing SQL Server Management Studio, but not SQL Server?

Comment: While installing SQL Server there's an option to install "Client Tools" only. Use it and actual SQL Server DB engine will not be installed.

Comment: While installing you have to install the SQL Server as a name instance in windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the install process, check that you actually install the `SQL Server Database Engine` and not only `SQL Server Management Studio`. Management Studio is only the client software to access an instance of SQL Server somewhere (locally or on a remote server), while the database engine is actually the server software of SQL Server, hosting actual databases.